# HostServices.showDocument: Default Application in Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx

How does the method `showDocument` in the class `HostServices` determine the application to execute the desired action in Linux?

I'm using Manjaro Linux and it always opens URLs in Firefox even though Chrome is defined as my standard browser. All the other applications I'm using are starting the correct browser when clicking a link.

There are several ways to define standard applications in Linux. I have checked quite a few now, but I haven't yet been able to find out which one JavaFX uses.

**Edit:**
Using `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI("http://www.google.de"))` works and opens the link in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since posted this question on the openjfx-dev-Mailinglist. The code which determines the default browser in Linux can be found in line 174 and following in the class [`HostServicesDelegate.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/jfx-dev/rt/file/dfe920ff7163/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/HostServicesDelegate.java).

Chromium is missing from the list of known browsers and that's what I'm using. This is the reason why this doesn't as expected on my machine. See also the [thread on the mailinglist](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-March/021584.html).